# Not able to get user info ( who commented ) of comments in a facebook page using graph api explorer

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all the comments and users who commented those.

Using graph API explorer, for a particular page using page access token, I am able to get all the comments for a post and users who commented.

But using facebook App, I am only able to get comments and not the users who commented.

The user has Admin role on that page.

following are the steps I am following :

1. This returns list of pages and there page access token.

   https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX
2. This returns the list of posts in that page

   https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/posts?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX
3. This returns the list of comments

   https://graph.facebook.com/{post-id}/comments?access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

In the last step I am suppose to get user details along with comment.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Your app probably needs to be reviewed, before you get access to that data again. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-4

Comment: are you sure? How am i suppose to make screencast since there is no interface. I am calling only page comment reading API.